# How to avoid identifier truncation in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I would like to drop all foreign keys associated to a table.

I first identify the foreign keys associated to it using the below

```
  SELECT DISTINCT constraint_name
  FROM information_schema.key_column_usage
  WHERE table_name = 'crm_campaign_offer_customer_groups'
  AND   table_schema = 'schema001'
  AND   constraint_name LIKE '%fkey%'
```

Then loop through each of these deleting the foreign keys using a statement like

```
ALTER TABLE crm_campaign_offer_customer_groups DROP CONSTRAINT crm_campaign_offer_customer_groups_variable_1_fkey1;
```

The issue that is occurring is that it first truncates the foreign key expression then tries to drop the truncated expression

```
NOTICE: identifier "..." will be truncated to "..."
ERROR: constraint "..." of relation "..." does not exist
```

It seems that it is truncating identifiers > 63 characters, but I'm hoping there is an alternative as the table and variable naming conventions are already set

Comment: Please provide a real name that exceeds 63 chars in your question. `crm_campaign_offer_customer_groups_variable_1_fkey1` is only 51... you seem to have built postgres with `NAMEDATALEN` more the default and then upgraded it?.. Otherwise I dont see how you created long names in first place. it should have truncated the name on `ADD CONSTRAINT`, so you would not have long name in `information_schema.key_column_usage`

Comment: Same error trying to run create function that return `RETURNS SETOF "TABLE(seq integer, path_id integer, path_seq integer, node bigint, edge bigint, cost double precision, agg_cost double precision)"` : ` identifier "TABLE(seq..." will be truncated to... ` and then `ERROR:  type "TABLE(seq integer, path_id integer, path_seq integer, node bigi" does not exist`

Answer (score 3):

For those that ended up here, check your key names closely. Postgres will have also pre-truncated the generated name on creation, so you will need to match this truncation on DROP to reference it correctly.

```
ALTER TABLE really_long_table_more_than_63_chars ADD PRIMARY KEY (fields);
```

->

```
ALTER TABLE really_long_table_more_than_63_chars DROP CONSTRAINT 
really_long_table_more_than_63_c_pkey;
```

Postgres behavior, when creating a constraint or index without specifying a name, appears to be:

Generate name as `{table_name}` + `_pkey` or `{table_name}` + `_check`

If above name.length is > 63 chars, truncate `{table_name}` short enough such that combined string is 63. i.e `{table_name}[:58]` + `_pkey` or `{table_name}[:57]` + `_check`